# template design for sending mail using nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is my code. When it runs in Postman it shows error like cannot get method.

```
var sendTempMail = function (req,res)   
{
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        auth: {
            user: 'transactions@gmail.com',
            pass: 'qwertyu@'
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'transactions@gmail.com',
        to: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com','yyyyyyyy@gmail.com',zzzzzz@mydomain.com,//here to:receiver not accept more than one 
        subject: 'mail notification Test',
        text: 'Hello !!!!!!!!!everything works fine'
        html:<h1>Notification mail</h1>

    <head>

    <style>

    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

             <table style="width:100%">

      <tr>

        <th>Firstname</th>

        <th>Lastname</th> 

        <th>Age</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Jill</td>

        <td>Smith</td>

        <td>50</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Eve</td>

        <td>Jackson</td>

        <td>94</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>John</td>

        <td>Doe</td>

        <td>80</td>

      </tr>

    </table>



    </body>

    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log("mail not sent" +error.message);
        }

        console.log('success');
    });
};

module.exports = {
    newTemplate :newTemplate,
    sendTempMail : sendTempMail
};
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the exact error message into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your error message with your question. However I can see one mistake that the HTML parameter has all raw html pasted there. It should be in string format.

Please check line no 44 in the code in below link
https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/examples/full.js

Comment: when i run this code i am getting cannot post this method error in postman.how i will write code for sending email html templates  using nodejs

Comment: What is the route URL in postman you are trying to call? Is it defined in your application routes? If postman is not able to find it that means either you are specifying it wrong in postman or it is wrong in application itself. Please verify that.

Comment: how to set table in html in this code for sending mail notification

Comment: html:<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>

Comment: in html i want to add to table